# How can fix anchor test error after installing rust?

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana, solana-cli, rustup

I installed rust on Ubuntu and checked that version but there's rustc version error.

```
myunixx@LAPTOP-JSMKVSS3:~$ rustup --version
rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `(error reading rustc version)`
```

I need 'rustc' to use `anchor test`. But I can't use it due to this error. I've reinstalled rust but there's no change. How can i fix this problem?

```
myunixx@LAPTOP-JSMKVSS3:~/myepicproject$ anchor test
Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: process didn't exit successfully: `rustc -vV` (exit status: 127)
--- stderr
/home/myunixx/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: error while loading shared libraries: /home/myunixx/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/libstd-7c582493123fc1dd.so: file too short
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was an issue installing `rustc`, even though you have `rustup`.  A few things you can try:

- maybe Rust can fix itself: run `rustup update`
- explicitly add a toolchain: run `rustup toolchain install stable`
- reinstall rustup: run `rustup self uninstall` and then go back through the instructions at https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install

More information about rustup at its book:
https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/index.html